# If I want my new hbase installation to use HDFS to store data, can I use hdfs://localhost:54310 as the hbase.rootdir?

Tags: linux, apache, hadoop, installation, hbase

I have hadoop-1.2.1 working properly on Linux Mint.

I want to add Apache HBase 0.94.

I just have one machine in pseudo-distributed mode.

My current hbase-site.xml looks like this:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
                <value>/home/user/hbase/zookeeper</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>localhost</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
                <value>2181</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

I tried starting up with start-hbase.sh and that didn't work because the HBASE shell didn't find zookeeper.

Next I tried starting up zookeeper separately with

```
./hbase-daemon.sh start zookeeper
```

I waited until the logs showed that zookeeper had started correctly, then I tried to start the master with

```
./hbase-daemon.sh start master
```

but the logs for the master showed:

```
2013-12-23 11:23:45,028 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2120)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
```

Answer (score 0):

A distributed Apache HBase installation depends on a running ZooKeeper cluster.It will start and stop the ZooKeeper ensemble as part of the HBase start/stop process. You can also manage the ZooKeeper ensemble independent of HBase and just point HBase at the cluster it should use.

To toggle HBase management of ZooKeeper, use the HBASE_MANAGES_ZK variable in conf/hbase-env.sh. This variable, which defaults to true, tells HBase whether to start/stop the ZooKeeper ensemble servers as part of HBase start/stop.

You can read this [link](http://hbase.apache.org/book/zookeeper.html) and understand about the zookeeper configuration with HBASE.
   In your case you started zookeeper manually and then HBASE also trys to start its own zookeeper.That is why `Cannot assign requested address` eroor is comming.

Comment: In fact, I checked my hbase-env.sh and it reads:  `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false` so I don't think that ZooKeeper will start automatically.  I will certainly read the link that you provided, and I will keep trying to get some kind of zookeeper started, either automatically or manually.  Thanks.